# Dual Monitor with a Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

Reading [this](http://www.splitview.com/node/40) I understood that is possible to use two monitors with Remote Desktop with equal resolutions. In my case I have 2 monitors with different resolution. Could I however use two monitors with my RDC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can with Vista and above, just run remote desktop with the width and height arguments instead of using `/span`.  The width should be the combined width of your two monitors, and the height should be the smallest monitor's height.

For example, if you're using 2 monitors at 1680x1050 and 1024x768, use 2704 for the width and 768 for height.

```
mstsc.exe /W:2704 /H:768
```

Resize  the window to it's full size and position so it fits both monitors from top to bottom. A nifty app you may also be interested in is [SplitView](http://www.splitview.com/), which makes things substantially easier.

Comment: Finally, as I understood, there will be no "really" dual monitor, but a only one "large" monitor, I mean, any "maximize left", "maximize right" will not work, and also I will see a snatch of my tallest monitor desktop.

Comment: You are correct. However with splitview, you can control which Window occupies which part of the monitor easily: http://www.splitview.com/SplitView-Personal-Edition